# Problema ao indexar website no google

Tags: seo

Boa noite,

E o seguinte estou com um problema ao indexar o meu site no google tenho conta criada no webmaster e adicionei o site enviei o `sitemap.xml` só que não indexa nada no google.
Eu tenho `login` para as pessoas se registarem e depois entrar na pagina penso que será esse o problema mas não estou a conseguir resolver por isso e que preciso da vossa ajuda para ver como poderei resolver.

Comment: A quanto tempo você mandou o site para indexação? Pois a indexação as vezes leva uma semana (apesar de ser bem mais rápida que antigamente).

Comment: 2 meses quase e nada eu já o tive indexado só que depois de fazer esse login perdi a indexação e não indexou mais ate agora

Comment: César tem uma área que mostra mensagens de erro, se não tiver nada recomendo remover e adicionar novamente.

Comment: César, como primeira sugestão, diria para dar uma olhada no seu arquivo [Robots.txt](http://larahvidotti.com.br/robots-txt).
Veja se ele está permitindo que a indexação aconteça e se seu sitemap também está linkado nele. Qual ferramenta está utilizando?
Wordpress?